# Cloudformation send pararameters to launchconfiguration start-script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a stack script which create a cluster with EFS, MySQL, and ASG with two servers.
I want to send some data to start-script such as RDS endpoint address and EFS filesystem id:

```
UserData:
    Fn::Base64:
      !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash -x
        sed -i 's/fs-086*****/\"!Ref EFSCreateFS/"' /etc/fstab
        mount -a
        rm -rf /var/www/html/wordpress/*
        cp /var/tmp/wpress.tar /var/www/html/wordpress/
        cd /var/www/html/wordpress/ && tar -xf wpress.tar
        sed -i 's/wordpress.cl******.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com/\"!GetAtt CreateDB.Endpoint.Address\"/' /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php
```

But requests !Ref EFSCreateFS and !GetAtt CreateDB.Endpoint.Address didn't convers to their parameters.
If someone has an idea how i can send parameters, please help.
Thank All in advance.

Comment: I think this is similar to the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549166/aws-cloudformation-userdata-passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-general.html#scenario-userdata-base64), you should include them using the same syntax like you would in CloudFormation. e.g. for YAML:

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub |
     Ref: MyValue
     Ref: MyName
     Hello World
```

You can also use a more bash-like syntax. Another example:

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub |
     ACCESS_KEY=${AccessKey}
     SECRET_KEY=${SecretKey}
```

In your case, you also need to pass a substitute variable for your `CreateDB.Endpoint.Address` attribute. Example:

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64:
    Fn::Sub:
      - |
        ACCESS_KEY=${AccessKey}
        SECRET_KEY=${SecretKey}
        echo "my db endpoint address ${MyDB}"
      - MyDB: !GetAtt CreateDB.Endpoint.Address
```

So, in your case that would become:

```
UserData:
    Fn::Base64:
      Fn::Sub:
        - |
          #!/bin/bash -x
          sed -i 's/fs-086*****/\"${EFSCreateFS}/"' /etc/fstab
          mount -a
          rm -rf /var/www/html/wordpress/*
          cp /var/tmp/wpress.tar /var/www/html/wordpress/
          cd /var/www/html/wordpress/ && tar -xf wpress.tar
          sed -i 's/wordpress.cl******.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com/\"${DBEndpointAddress}\"/' /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php
        - DBEndpointAddress: !GetAtt CreateDB.Endpoint.Address
```

The following answer might also help you out: [UserData script with Resource Attribute CloudFormation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625737/userdata-script-with-resource-attribute-cloudformation)

Comment: Thank you. It works. But without gaps(/")
          Fn::Sub:
            - |
              #!/bin/bash -x
              sed -i 's/fs-086***/${EFSCreateFS}/' /etc/fstab
              mount -a
              rm -rf /var/www/html/wordpress/*
              cp /var/tmp/wpress.tar /var/www/html/wordpress/
              cd /var/www/html/wordpress/ && tar -xf wpress.tar
              sed -i 's/wordpres****.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com/${DBEndpointAddress}/' /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php
            - DBEndpointAddress: !GetAtt CreateDB.Endpoint.Address